# Node.js Callback doesn´t execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, mongodb-query

I have setup an API which looks up a request in a MongoDB and returns the result as JSON Objects. I had set it up earlier all in a main.js but now i want to modularize it and have shifted the mongo stuff to a queryMongo.js which gets called in the POST request of the main.js (I use POST instead of get to avoid GET limitations)
So here is the main.js using express:

```
dataRouter.route('/data')
.post(function(req, res){
    var query =req.query;

    getResult(query, function(err, data){
        console.log('query done');
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    });
```

The getResult function is defined in a queryMongo.js

```
module.exports.getResult = function (query){

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

const dbName = 'MyDB';

function processResult(docs){
  var result = docs;
  module.exports.result=result;
}

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");


  const db = client.db(dbName);

  findDocuments(db, function(docs) {
    processResult(docs);
    client.close();
  });
});

const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('myCollection');
    collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      callback(docs);   
    });
  };
};
```

Everything stand alone is working fine, but the getResult function doesn´t get to execute the callback, i.e. res.json(data) or even the console.log('query done') aren´t executed. The first part of the function getResult(query) is working fine, i.e. the function get´s invoked and the query is conducted as I can see from a console.log with the results showing up. Has anyone an idea why the callbacks aren´t executed?

Comment: your function getResult doesnt take the callback as parameter you only define one argument the query

Comment: You don't define a callback argument for your `getResult()` function and you don't call a callback when everything is done inside of `getResult()`.  Callbacks in node.js are not automatic.  You have to define them as arguments, pass them as an argument (the only part of this you are doing) and execute them yourself inside your function at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, that worked! I added now a done argument to getResult `module.exports.getResult = function (query, done){` and then call done inside of the findDocuments function `findDocuments(db, function(docs) { done(docs); client.close(); });`
I also realized that I actually don´t need the processResult function.